# How modify character arrays inside functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I want to update a character array by reversing it. The character array is correct when output inside function, but not in `main` after the function is called.

I believe that the character array is passed by reference, but when updating the array, the character array in the main function is not updated. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void StringReverse(char *ch, int size){
    char sh[100] = {0};
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
        sh[i] = ch[size-1-i];
    }
    sh[size] = '\0';
    ch = sh;
    cout<<ch<<endl;
}

int main(){
    char ch[100];
    cin.getline(ch, 100);
    int size = strlen(ch);
    StringReverse(ch,size);
    cout<<ch;
}
```

I do not want to print the result inside the function, but update the character array 'ch' in the `main` function by calling the function `StringReverse`.

Comment: _"I believe that the character array is ..."_. *Believing* is a dangerous thing. I would test anything first and be sure about it, then just go on belief.

Comment: You want to use `strncpy()` instead of `ch = sh;`.

Comment: Changing the copy of the pointer in `StringReverse` doesn't change the pointer to a stack variable in another function. Even if it worked, you still want to use a local stack variable, which is a big "no"! Just use a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `strncpy()` instead of `ch = sh;`. As other people have kindly pointed, you are not modifying `ch`. You are modifying the local variable `sh` only.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void StringReverse(char *ch, int size){
    char sh[100] = {0};
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
        sh[i] = ch[size-1-i];
    }
    sh[size] = '\0';
    strncpy(ch, sh, 100);
    cout<<ch<<endl;
}

int main(){
    char ch[100];
    cin.getline(ch, 100);
    int size = strlen(ch);
    StringReverse(ch,size);
    cout<<ch;
}
```

Comment: OP should use `string` instead.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, Indeed. The question is tagged `c++` but then again he is using `char arrays` and including the `cstring` header file. It is a bit of both worlds. :P

Comment: Yes. Using the strings would make it a lot easier I know. I am just clearing out my concepts :P @MatthieuBrucher

Comment: @sparrow `ch` is actually passed by value, i.e., you are passing a pointer by value (because array decay to pointers), so `ch` in `StringReverse` is actually a copy of the pointer `ch` in the `main` function. When you do `ch = sh`, you modify `ch`, the copy, and not the original `ch`. `strncpy` works on the "pointed" array, which is why it works because both the original and the copy points to the same array.

Comment: @Holt, deleted my comment in deference to your explanation. I could not have explained it as good.

Comment: Thank you so much guys Joey and @Holt. The concept is now more clear to me. :)

Comment: Is there an option to do this with passing a reference to the char pointer? Like, with having "char*& ch" in the signature?

Answer (score 0):

The `ch` in `StringReverse` function is local to that function. And that's why when assign `ch = sh;`, it doesn't change the `ch` in `main`.
While you can copy `sh`, a better approach is to use reverse *in-place* so that you wouldn't need a local copy at all.

For example:

```
void StringReverse(char *ch, int size){
    for(int i = 0, j= size - 1 ; i < j ; i++, j--){
        int t = ch[i];
        ch[i] = ch[j];
        ch[j] = t;
    }
    cout << ch << endl;
}
```

If you use `std::string` instead of a plain char array, it would be a lot easier to do this. You could for example use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Comment: You can use `std::reverse` on a simple array, just use `ch` and `ch + size` for the iterator.

Comment: That's a way better solution. Thanks :)

Comment: @sparrow If it's an exercise then you're probably expected to implement it rather than use  C++ standard library to do everything (so plain array is OK). But you could still go for a better algorithm.